# C# How to get Network Adapter Metric?

Tags: networking

I want to get 'Metric' of a specific network adapter in Windows. How can I do this by using C# code?

I can get all network adapters by using this code but I can't figure out how to get 'Metric'.

```
       foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
       {
               //??
       }
```

Comment: Metrics are applied to routes, not interfaces.

Comment: @RonMaupin In Windows 10 there is a metric associated with the interface too, it can be directly set in the interface settings. It is kind of a replacement to the Binding Order if I understand correctly.

Comment: Check out this PInvoke code, it retrieves the metric through WinApi. It seems NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces just doesn't return that information. https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.getadaptersaddresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the [Get-NetIPInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipinterface?view=win10-ps) PowerShell cmdlet that returns the interface metric:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-NetIPInterface");
// ps.AddParameter("AddressFamily", "IPv4"); 
Collection<PSObject> psObjects = ps.Invoke();

foreach (PSObject psObject in psObjects)
{    
    foreach (PSPropertyInfo propInfo in psObject.Properties)
    {
        // extract values...
    }
}
```

This might contain all the information you need, so you don't have to use `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`. However if you still want to map the 2 results you can use the AddressFamily (IPv4/IPv6) and the interface index.
Get-NetIPInterface returns "InterfaceIndex" and "AddressFamily" properties both being an integer. You can convert the second to a [System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.addressfamily?view=netframework-4.8) enum value. On NetworkInterface you can access the interface index by `GetIPProperties().GetIPv4Properties().Index` or `GetIPProperties().GetIPv6Properties().Index` depending on the address family you are interested in.

Comment: That index property is not what I put into it in the Windows adapter properties...